# Python requests.json() object as dictionary does not recognize its own keys with hasattr() or value in object.keys() call

Tags: python, json, mongodb, dictionary

Summary: dictionary/json object indicates it does not have a given key (using either a `hasattr` call or a `value in object.keys` boolean test even though that key shows up in an `object.keys()` call. So how can I access the value for that key?

Longer version: I am quite puzzled trying to parse some json coming back from an API. When I try to determine whether the json object, which is showing up as a dictionary, has a given key, the code returns false for the key even when it shows the key is there for the object.

Here is how I am retrieving the json:

```
   r = requests.get(url, headers = {'User-Agent':UA})

    try:
        print(r.json())
        jsonobject = r.json()
        print("class of jsonobject is %s"%jsonobject.__class__.__name__)
        print("here are dictionary keys %s"%jsonobject.keys())
        if hasattr(jsonobject, 'laps') and jsonobject['laps'] is not None:
            ...
        else:
            print("no laps object")

        if hasattr(jsonobject, 'points') and jsonobject['points'] is not None:
           ...
```

The reason I am doing this is that often I am getting encoding errors from the field nested within the 'laps' array or the 'points' array so that I cannot insert the json data into a MongoDB database. I would like to delete these fields from the json object since they don't contain useful information anyway.

The problem is that the json object is always returning false for hasattr(jsonobject, 'laps') and hasattr(jsonobject,'points'. It returned false even in the case of a record where I then printed out the keys and they showed:

```
here are dictionary keys dict_keys(['is_peptalk_allowed', 'show_workout', 'hydration', 'records', 'include_in_stats', 'expand', 'pb_count', 'start_time', 'calories', 'altitude_max', 'hashtags', 'laps', 'pictures', 'duration', 'playlist'\
, 'sport', 'points', 'show_map', 'local_start_time', 'speed_avg', 'tagged_users', 'distance', 'altitude_min', 'is_live', 'author', 'feed_id', 'speed_max', 'id'])
```

So I thought perhaps the dict was behaving strangely with hasattr, and rewrote the code as:

```
if 'laps' in jsonobject.keys() and jsonobject['laps'] is not None:
```

but that also returns false even thoug hit again prints the same array of keys that does include 'laps'.

Comment: Don't use `key in dict.keys()` when `key in dict` will do.

Comment: `hasattr()` tests for **attributes**. Dictionary keys are not attributes. `hasattr(dict, key)` will always fail unless `key` is an actual dictionary attribute such as `keys` or `items`.

Comment: If `'laps'` is present but the *value* is set to `None`, then your `is not None` test is going to be false. That doesn't mean the key is not present.

Comment: @MartijnPieters when laps is present it is never None so far as I have seen in the data - I have that in there just to be careful. But you were correct that key in dict worked even though key in dict.values was not working.

Comment: You are using confusing language there. Are you using `jsonobject.values()`? That'll never contain `'lap'` because values are not keys. You are also omitting the `()` from `jsonobject.keys` and `jsonobject.values`. Without calling those methods the `in` test will certainly fail (with an exception).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry you are right I was using confusing language. I was using keys() not values or values()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hasattr()` is entirely the wrong tool to use. It tests for attributes, but dictionary keys are not attributes.

To test for keys, use the `in` test *directly against the dictionary*:

```
if 'lap' in jsonobject:
```

Calling `jsonobject.keys()` is redundant and creates a new dictionary view object.

It'll be true for your dictionary, but that's not the only thing you are testing for. Your test is:

```
if 'lap' in jsonobject and jsonobject['lap'] is not None:
```

That'll fail if `'lap'` is a key but the value in the dictionary is `None`.

The above test can be more simply and compactly stated as:

```
if jsonobject.get('lap') is not None:
```

If `None` is a valid value, don't test for it; stick to just `'lap' in jsonobject`.